# Adding all images from a folder into an array

Tags: android, arrays

I'm wanting to add a large amount of images to an image array and I'm wondering if there is a way to add all the images in a specified folder rather than adding all of them manually in big list.

Comment: add the locations of the images, to the array rather and get them when you need

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you want this should make a job:
`File folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
+ "/folderWithImages";`
`File list[] = file.listFiles();`
This will give you array of files in directory. Only I dont remember that adding slash is necessary.

Comment: in your code snippet who is `file`? i didn't want to change it that is why i am verifying if its intentional-because it should be `folder`

Comment: Yeah it should be folder, you are right. It was unintentional mistake :)

Comment: folder is being detected as a string rather than a file would this be due to the file directory being wrong?